# quiz generator using fractions

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am a math teacher a need a way to create word problems and test students on those problems. Because i want to be able to retest these students i needed a way to recreate the same question and display answer choices that would be different each time based on the problem given. So i used arrays to hold variable information like names locations or foods that come up in the word problem.

Ex dave has 1 apple on monday. Dave goes to the store and gets 3 more apples. How many apples does dave have?

So currently i am able to create a name array, fruit array, location array to replace the (name fruit or location) each time the question is ask.

My issue is how do i add fractions to both the answers and the possible choices?. My second issue is i need a way to provide numbers and words  in the answer. I have attached the example of questions i am trying to create.

Currently i have multiple choice and open end answers that work based on adding a random amount to the actual answer.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TlWBy.jpg)

Comment: please share your code which you have tried

Comment: Are you struggling with rendering / displaying a given fraction or is your question about how to represent a fraction as an array element?

Comment: http://mathjs.org/docs/datatypes/fractions.html can represent fractions precsiely and easily

Comment: are you looking for something like this- http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/JWMVzE

Comment: Currently this is what i have http://math.pageupnow.com/

Comment: `i needed a way to recreate the same question and display answer choices that would be different each time based` sounds like a seeded PRNG to me

Comment: Currently this is what i have math.pageupnow.com  my issue is that i need each question to be randomize and display the correct answer and 3 other multiple choice options that are wrong. This was easy for a (dave has 4 apples on monday and 3 on tuesday how many does he have in total?

Comment: Because i added 4 + 3 which is 7 then added a random number to the answer for all the other wrong options. It is hard to do this for a fraction and also harder to have an option for numbers and words in the answer. Long story short i need to create a real quiz generator that can do fractions and give fraction answers that are both wrong and correct in a multiple a b c d option.

Answer (score 0):

sry, but your code is so awfully cluttered and redundant, I didn't want to dir through all that.

So I made a simple example that generates "random" sentences by utilizing a PRNG (Mersenne Twister)

```js
//I'll add the non minified version
prng=function(){"use strict"
function n(r,t){function e(){var n=r,e=t,u=n[e],o=n[t=623>e?e+1:0],i=n[227>e?e+397:e-227]
return n[e]=i^(2147483648&u|2147483647&o)>>>1^(1&o&&2567483615),u^=u>>>11,u^=u<<7&2636928640,u^=u<<15&4022730752,u^=u>>>18,u>>>0}var u={uint32:e,float(){return e()/4294967296},double(){return(e()>>>6)/67108864+(e()>>>5)/9007199254740992},seed(n){var e=n>>>0||5489,o=1
for(r[0]=e,t=0;624>o;++o)e^=e>>>30,e=(r[o]=(1812433253*(e>>>16)<<16)+1812433253*(65535&e)+o)>>>0
return u},clone(){return n(new Uint32Array(r),t)}}
return u}return n(new Uint32Array(624),0).seed(4294967296*Math.random()).clone}()

//the actual application
var target = document.querySelector('#sentences');
var seed = document.querySelector('#seed');
var numRows = document.querySelector('#numRows');
seed.onchange = numRows.onchange = update;



const protagonists = ['Beth', 'Chris', 'Carl', 'April', 'Cinnamon','Ethan', 'Sammy', 'Dan', 'Devron', 'Livron', 'Paul', 'the Frog', 'the Dog', 'the Hamster'];

const actions = ['saw', 'walked to', 'jumped onto', 'hit', 'got bitten by', 'kissed'];

//create a new prng
var random = prng();

//a utility
function sample(array){
 return array[ Math.floor(random.float() * array.length) ];
}

function update(){
 //re-seed the prng
  random.seed(+seed.value);
  
  //flush the seeded values out of the buffer
  for(var i=1234; i--; random.float());
  
  var rows = Array(+numRows.value);
  for(var i = 0; i<rows.length; ++i){
   var a = sample(protagonists), 
     b = sample(protagonists),
      action = sample(actions);
      
    while(a === b) b = sample(protagonists);
    
    rows[i] = `<li>${a} ${action} ${b}</li>`;
  }
  
  target.innerHTML = `<ul>${ rows.join("\n") }</ul>`;
}

update();
```

```html
<label>
  Seed for the PRNG: 
  <input id="seed" type="number" min=0 step=1 value="42"/>
</label>
<br>
<label>
  number of generated rows: 
  <input id="numRows" type="number" min=0 step=1 value="5"/>
</label>

<div id="sentences"></div>
```

Play a bit with the inputs. The point of this example is to show how this prng always generates the same "random" expresions for the same seed.

If you check out the code, yuu'll see that id doesn't cache any sentences or so, they are generated from scratch each time you change one of the inputs.

And the not-minified version of the prng:

```
prng = (function(){
    'use strict';

    //implementing a mersenne-twister with 32bit 
    function _mt19937(buffer, i){
        function uint32() {
            var $ = buffer,
                j = i,
                a = $[j], 
                b = $[i = j<623? j+1: 0],
                c = $[j<227? j+397: j-227];

            $[j] = c ^ ((0x80000000 & a | 0x7FFFFFFF & b) >>> 1) ^ (b&1 && 0x9908b0df);

            a ^= a >>> 11;
            a ^= (a << 7) & 0x9d2c5680;
            a ^= (a << 15) & 0xefc60000;
            a ^= a >>> 18;
            return a >>> 0;
        }
        var me = {
            //0 <= uint32() < 4294967296
            uint32,

            //0 <= float() < 1 with 32bit precision
            float(){
                return uint32() / 4294967296;
            },

            //0 <= double() < 1 with 53bit precision (throwing 11 bit away)
            double(){
                return (uint32()>>>6) / 67108864 + (uint32()>>>5) / 9007199254740992;
            },

            //(re-)seed the internal state
            seed(seed){
                var a = seed>>>0 || 5489, j = 1;
                for(buffer[0] = a, i = 0; j<624; ++j){
                    a ^= a>>>30;
                    a = (buffer[j] = ((0x6c078965 * (a >>> 16)) << 16) + 0x6c078965 * (0xffff & a) + j)>>>0;
                }
                return me;
            },

            //create a new instance that has the same state.
            //states are not shared, they develop individually
            clone(){
                return _mt19937(new Uint32Array(buffer), i);            
                //return _mt19937(buffer.slice(), i);           
            }
        }

        return me;
    }

    //create a prototype, seed it with a random number (per page and request)
    //each generated instance will start as a clone of this, 
    //and return the same sequence
    //unless you (re-)seed them
    return _mt19937(new Uint32Array(624),0).seed( Math.random() * 4294967296 ).clone;
    //return _mt19937(new Array(624),0).seed( Math.random() * 4294967296 ).clone;
})();
```